# Dim webpage with modal ontop

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a page that I dim when the user submits a form. When the dim element is activated on the page, a modal is also activated. My issue is that the modal is dimmed as well. I tried using z-index to have the modal ontop of the .dimmer div would prevent the dimmwr attributes from affecting the modal.

```
# HTML
<div class="dimmer">
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="after_submit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
</div>

# CSS
.dimmer {
  display: none;
  background: #000;
  opacity: 0.5;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
}

#after_submit {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
}

# JS
$(function() {
    $('#wizard_submit').validate();
    $('#wizard_submit').submit(function(event) {
        var isvalidate = $("#wizard_submit").valid();
        if (isvalidate) {
            $('.dimmer').show();
            $('#after_submit').modal('show');
        }
    });
});
```

The background of #000 with an opacity of 0.5 is applying to the after_submit element as well. I would like the prevent that from happening.

Comment: please create a fiddle or code snippet recreating the problem you ar having.

Comment: What are you using to display your modal?  I would be surprised if that didn't have an option for doing a dimming overlay.  If whatever you're using doesn't, I suggest finding an alternative that does :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/svaidhyanath/pmy4q84o/  is this what you were looking for?

Comment: @sai That works well. If you want to post the code I can mark as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the `display: none` to your "#after_submit" modal so that it is also hidden from view just like the dimmer class. Now basically you want to bind the click element to a button, in your case the submit button, and while you are performing your validations and such, add the show functions to the script.

Here is and example **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/svaidhyanath/pmy4q84o/)** here

Code snippet as follows..

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#clickMe').click(function() {
    $('.dimmer').show();
    $('#after_submit').show();
  });
});
```

```css
.dimmer {
  display: none;
  background: #000;
  opacity: 0.5;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
}
#after_submit {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: #fff;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -100px -100px;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="clickMe">Click Me</button>
<div class="dimmer"></div>
<div id="after_submit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <p>modal stuff goes here</p>
</div>
```

Hope this helps. **Happy Coding :)**